# How do you get results where all properties under the same client are inactive but the client isn't inactive?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one with Client Address information called `ClientData`, and one with information on their properties called `PropertyData`. In both tables, there is a `Status` field to indicate whether or not the client is inactive and both tables have a field called `ClientID` to indicate which client the property belongs to. I'm trying to figure out a query that will find clients where **ALL** of the properties under the same `ClientID` have `PropertyData.Status ='INACTIVE'` but `ClientData.Status` isn't marked INACTIVE.

Sorry if my question is unclear. This is my first time using Stack Overflow.

Haven't figured out any queries on this yet.

Comment: For some tips on how you could improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientData.ClientID
FROM ClientData
JOIN PropertyData ON ClientData.ClientID = PropertyData.ClientID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM PropertyData
    WHERE PropertyData.ClientID = ClientData.ClientID
    AND PropertyData.Status != 'INACTIVE')
AND ClientData.Status != 'INACTIVE'
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I needed. Appreciate the help.